# Photoshop filter menu is greyed out

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Why is part of the menu greyed out? I need to access the blur gallery.
The image is a .jpg. The mode is 8 Bits/Channel and RGB Color.

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite running Photoshop Creative Cloud (2014.2.2 release).

[image]

Comment: what's type of your documents ?

Comment: This appears to be a technical support question, not a design question.

Comment: .jpg @DevelopersPedia

Comment: You are aware that some filters are not available for 16-bit images, right?
What platform, Macintosh or Windows?  What exact version of the OS? 
 Whats your Photoshop version?
Please read this FAQ for advice on how to ask your questions correctly for quicker and better answers, Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome @RebeccaHarris

Comment: **Some** of those filters would work in any selected mode. If you had a layer set to not visible and then selected it (intentionally, or using "auto-select layer"), then the entire list would be greyed out. If you had a uncommitted transform active, then the whole list would be greyed out as well. Check for selection states etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't figure out what's wrong and you don't mind losing all your settings, you can try resetting all of your Photoshop settings by:

Quitting Photoshop

Opening it back up while holding Command, Option, and Shift at the same time and holding them until Photoshop brings up the following question.

It will ask if you want to "Delete the Photoshop Settings File?"

Click yes

Then see if the filters work as expected.